# Email notifications not working using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I will preface this saying that I know almost nothing about rails. But I am trying to fix this issue involving rails so any help would be greatly appreciated (and also, if you could dumb it down for me that would be great!)

We have a rails email notification set up for two of our sites. If a user fills out an application on our English site, then a notification email is sent to **person A.** If a user fills out an application on our French site, then a notification email is sent to **person B.**

However, at the moment it seems like all emails are going to person A regardless of whether an application is filled out on the English or French site. How can I fix this?

Here is the code from the admin_mailer.rb file:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'noreply@canwise.com'

  def contact_email
    @contact = Contact.last
    mail to: 'email1@1test.com'

  end

  def application_email
    @application = Application.last
    mail to: 'email1@test.com'
  end

  def eps_contact_email
    @contact = Contact.last
    mail to: "email2@test.com"
  end

  def eps_application_email
    @application = Application.last
    mail to: 'email2@test.com'
  end

  def salesforce_application_failure(application)
    subject = "Application #{application.id} submitted by #{application.firstName} #{application.lastName} failed to submit to salesforce."
    mail(to: 'test@test.com', subject: subject) do |format|
      format.text { render text: '' }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the code from the application.rb file:

```
def email_notification
    if provider == 'www.frenchsite.com'
      AdminMailer.eps_application_email.deliver
    else
      AdminMailer.application_email.deliver
    end
  end
```

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

If the emails are all going to email1@test.com, then it only means that your provider for french is not matching 'www.frenchsite.com'. The 'if' statement is always resulting in false.

Comment: do you mean that perhaps there is a typo in the www.frenchsite.com somewhere in the code?

Comment: I just checked all the website urls in the code and they are correct! what else could it be???

Comment: Can you change the code:
    'if provider == 'www.frenchsite.com'
      AdminMailer.eps_application_email.deliver
    else
      AdminMailer.eps_application_email.deliver
    end'

And check if the mails are now delivered to email2@test.com

Comment: Log out the value of `provider` and see what it actually is set to.

Comment: Sonali, nothing changed when I added your code:( any other ideas?

Comment: Max Willians, what do you mean by log out-sorry total newbie here.

Comment: Put this before 'if' loop `raise provider.inspect`

and check terminal